# Fitting signal with background with scipy curve_fit()

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

Below is a toy model of my current problem. I have a background with a shape of wide gaussian and a sharp signal peak that is slighly off-centered from the background mean.
I want to extract the properties of the sharp peak (i.e. width, peak loc, and etc). Here is a link to the plot with failed fits to the peak:

[image: graph of background + offset signal].

For initial guess of the parameters, weirdly, when a value much larger than the actual standard deviation of the distribution is used, the fit performs better...something is wrong, but can't figure out. I would appreciate for any tips on fitting peaks with backgrounds.

Below is what I tried.

```
#Fake Data
data  = np.random.normal(loc=3.25, scale=0.01, size=15000)
data2 = np.random.normal(loc=3.0, scale=0.3, size=25000)

#Bins
bins  = np.arange(0, 6.1, 0.1)

#Hitogram with its defined bins
data_entries_1, bins = np.histogram(data, bins=bins)
data_entries_2, bins = np.histogram(data2, bins=bins)

#Add two generated histograms - Final y data
data_entries = data_entries_1 + data_entries_2

#Cetner of each bins - Final x data
bin_centers = np.array([0.5*(bins[i] + bins[i+1]) for i in range(len(bins)-1)])

#fit func 1
def fit_func1(x, A, mu, sigma):
    #Define functions here
    first_func  = A*np.exp(-1.0*(x - mu)**2 / (2*sigma**2))
    return first_func

#fit func 2
def fit_func2(x, B, mu2, sigma2):
    #Define functions here
    second_func = B*np.exp(-1.0*(x - mu2)**2 / (2*sigma2**2))
    return second_func

#total fit function
def fit_func(x, A, mu, sigma, B, mu2, sigma2):
    #Define functions here
    first_func  = A*np.exp(-1.0*(x - mu)**2 / (2*sigma**2))
    second_func = B*np.exp(-1.0*(x - mu2)**2 / (2*sigma2**2))
    final_func  = first_func + second_func
    return final_func

#Fit it
popt1, pconv1 = curve_fit(fit_func1, xdata=bin_centers, ydata=data_entries_1, p0=[20000, 3.25, 1.])
popt2, pconv2 = curve_fit(fit_func2, xdata=bin_centers, ydata=data_entries_2, p0=[2000, 3.0, 0.3])
popt, pconv   = curve_fit(fit_func, xdata=bin_centers, ydata=data_entries, p0=[20000, 3.25, 1.,\
                                                                           2000, 3.0, 0.3])

# Generate enough x values to make the curves look smooth.
xspace = np.linspace(0, 6, 100)

# Plot the histogram and the fitted function.
plt.step(bin_centers, data_entries, label=r'Histogram entries')
plt.plot(xspace, fit_func1(xspace, *popt1), label='Fitted function1')
plt.plot(xspace, fit_func2(xspace, *popt2), label='Fitted function2')
plt.plot(xspace, fit_func(xspace, *popt), label='Fitted function', linestyle="--")
plt.xlim(1, 5)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**UPDATE**
Following the suggestions from the selected answer, bin width is reduced to be smaller than the sigma of the actual peak to be fitted. Also, to reduce the # of free parameters to fit, mu of the fitting gaussian function is fixed to a constant (actual mean of the distribution).

```
#Generate Fake Data
data  = np.random.normal(loc=3.25, scale=0.04, size=15000)
data2 = np.random.normal(loc=3.0, scale=0.3, size=25000)

#Bins
bins  = np.arange(0, 6.1, 0.02)

#Compute mean to use as contraints when fitting
mids = np.array([0.5*(bins[i] + bins[i+1]) for i in range(len(bins)-1)])
mean_1 = np.average(mids, weights=data_entries_1)
mean_2 = np.average(mids, weights=data_entries_2)

#fit func 1
def fit_func1(x, A, sigma):
    #Define functions here
    first_func  = A*np.exp(-1.0*(x - mean_1)**2 / (2*sigma**2))
    return first_func

#fit func 2
def fit_func2(x, B, sigma2):
    #Define functions here
    second_func = B*np.exp(-1.0*(x - mean_2)**2 / (2*sigma2**2))
    return second_func

#total fit function
def fit_func(x, A, sigma, B, sigma2):
    #Define functions here
    first_func  = A*np.exp(-1.0*(x - mean_1)**2 / (2*sigma**2))
    second_func = B*np.exp(-1.0*(x - mean_2)**2 / (2*sigma2**2))
    final_func  = first_func + second_func
    return final_func
```

[image]

Comment: Your example code gives an error because of `xspace`.

Comment: Sorry, just updated the missing part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems.

1. the `plt.step` function does not do what you think it does. It takes the edges of the bins, not the centers of the bin.
2. The rarrow peak is a normal distribution with a sigma much smaller than the bin width. Essentially, you try to fit a three-parameter function (A, mu, sigma) on a single (x, y) value; this is bound to fail. The outcome of this fit is not reproducible on my system; rerunning the same code will sometimes even generate an error depending on the random generator output.

See below for an illustration of these points.

[image: Close-up of multi-gauss fit]

```
def normal(x, sigma):
    a = 0.5/sigma**2
    return np.sqrt(a/np.pi) * np.exp(-a*x**2)
    
def truefunc(x):
    return 1500*normal(x-3.25, 0.01) + 2500*normal(x-3.0, 0.3)

plt.close('all')
xspace = np.linspace(3, 3.5, 200)
plt.plot(bin_centers, data_entries, 'ko', label=r'Histogram entries')
plt.plot(xspace, truefunc(xspace), label='True distribution')
plt.plot(xspace, fit_func1(xspace, *popt1), label='Fitted function1')
plt.plot(xspace, fit_func2(xspace, *popt2), label='Fitted function2')
plt.plot(xspace, fit_func(xspace, *popt), label='Fitted function', linestyle="--")
plt.xlim(3, 3.5)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

So, you will need to decrease the bin size so that you can actually resolve the width of the narrow peak, or redefine `fit_func1` to take two parameters: peak height and peak position (mu). Fix sigma to `bin_width/6`. You'll have to postprocess the fit result to get the area under the peak consistent with the histogram.

If you decrease the bin size, the histogram will be noisy. It's probably a good idea to use the `sigma` parameter of `curve_fit`; set it to

```
np.sqrt(data_entries + 0.25)
```

This is statistically not completely correct, but it's much better than assuming a fixed error on all histogram entries. (You can play with the 0.25 value; it should be > 0 and < 1).

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to analyze the peak properties you can go without fitting. To get the peak position just do:

```
peak_pos = bin_centers[data_entries.argmax()]
```

If you have multiple such peaks you could also use [`scipy.signal.find_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html).

To get the peak width you can use [`scipy.signal.peak_widths`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.peak_widths.html). Optionally you can fit the background broad Gaussian and subtract before analyzing the peak.